# TypeError: 'fp' is not a file-like object or it does not take bytes: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I hope I have added everything needed necessary to find out what's wrong with the code. When working on my website, I keep getting this error. According to the traceback, I believe the source of this problem is in views.py with either `simquestion = db.session.query(Tournamentsim.question).order_by(func.random()).limit(1)` and/or `tts.save(file_location)`. When I use `'hello'` instead of `simquestion`, it works. That's why I believe there's something wrong when I try to get a question from `Tournamentsim`. I have been looking at similar questions but can't seem to find the answer. I hope I can find some help. Here's the code:

models.py

```
class Tournamentsim(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question=db.Column(db.String(1000))
    answer=db.Column(db.String(500))
```

views.py

```
    @views.route('/test-yourself/tournament-simulator')
    @login_required
    def test_yourself_tournament_simulator():
        generated_audio_filename = secrets.token_hex(10) + ".mp3"
    
        simquestion = db.session.query(Tournamentsim.question).order_by(func.random()).limit(1)   
    
        tts = gTTS(simquestion, lang='en')
        
        file_location = os.path.join(
            app.config["AUDIO_FILE_UPLOAD"],
            generated_audio_filename
        )
    
        tts.save(file_location)
    
        return render_template(
            "test-yourself/tournament-simulator.html", 
            title="Hello",
            user=current_user, 
            audio=True, 
            file=generated_audio_filename
        )
```

Here's the traceback:
[Traceback (most recent call last) (Part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXOCe.jpg) 
[During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: (Part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmx9l.jpg)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the fact that you don't pass a requested character string, but the database query as a whole.

To get just the text of a random question, the keyword `first()` is missing. You can do without a limit here because exactly one element is requested. However, a tuple containing the text of the question is returned. So the exact query is as follows.

```py
question_text = db.session.query(Tournamentsim.question)\
        .order_by(func.random())
        .first()[0]
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following expression.

```py
question_text = Tournamentsim.query\
        .order_by(func.random())\
        .with_entities(Tournamentsim.question)\
        .first()[0]
```

Here is the entire code of the simple example.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    send_from_directory
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func
from gtts import gTTS
import os, secrets 


db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///'+os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'sample.db'),
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
    UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
)

for folder in (app.instance_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],):
    try: 
        os.makedirs(folder)
    except OSError: 
        pass

db.init_app(app)

class Tournamentsim(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question = db.Column(db.String)
    answer = db.Column(db.String)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    ts = [Tournamentsim(question=f'q-{i}', answer=f'a-{i}') for i in range(20)]
    db.session.add_all(ts)
    db.session.commit()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    filename = secrets.token_hex(10) + '.mp3'
    filepath = os.path.join(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
        filename 
    )

    q,*_ = Tournamentsim.query\
        .order_by(func.random())\
        .with_entities(Tournamentsim.question)\
        .first()
    tts = gTTS(q, lang='en')
    tts.save(filepath)

    return render_template('index.html', file=filename)

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
        filename, 
        mimetype='audio/mpeg', 
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="{{ url_for('download', filename=file) }}" controls></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

As a hint:
You can also deliver the audio file directly without saving it.

```py
from flask import send_file
import io

# ...

@app.route('/question')
def question():
    q,*_ = Tournamentsim.query\
        .order_by(func.random())\
        .with_entities(Tournamentsim.question)\
        .first()
    tts = gTTS(q, lang='en')
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    tts.write_to_fp(fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        fp, 
        mimetype='audio/mpeg', 
        download_name='question.mp3', 
        as_attachment=True
    )
```